# How to mount.cifs for writing in home network

Tags: 12.04, permissions, cifs

I need to mount a directory `/home/MyUser/Share` to another computer as an equivalent to `smb://IP_address/share` that enables me writing into files there via Nautilus.

Even for MyUser being a **sudoer**, my attempts

```
sudo mount -t cifs //IP_address/share /home/MyUser/Share -o username=User_at_IP_address,noexec<
```

or

```
sudo mount.cifs //IP_address/share /home/MyUser/Share -rw
```

enable reading only and

```
sudo mount --make-shared /home/MyUser/Share
```

does not enable writing, too.

A **standard user** can use `pkexec`  instead of `sudo`  or change his account via the `su` command, but the problem with user rights to write is then even greater.
Please advise me the correct steps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/root/.credentials,uid=myusernameonclient,gid=users //IP_address_share /home/myusername/mountpoint
```

I think this: uid=myusernameonclient,gid=users is what you will need to change.
The .credential file includes

```
username=myusernameOntheserver
password=mypasswordtoaccesstheshare
domain=thedomainname
```

You will not need that, if you access the share without credentials.

Comment: Please advise me with the file .credentials. Thanks!

Comment: modified the answer accordingly. Though, if the share is not password protected you can omit the credentials=/root/.credentials,

Comment: The share with the IP_address is password protected. Mere omitting 'the credentials=/root/.credentials' has not helped to mount it 'rw' even for a sudoer.

Comment: Did you try creating the credential file and running the command as above? How is the share exported on the server?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what the '/root/.credentials' file should contain. The server uses Windows XP.

Comment: the file should contain username="your username on the xp machine", password="the respective password". You may omit the domain part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29354/discussion-between-bruni-and-tomas-peceny).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly test it:

```
$ sudo mount.cifs //your_server/share ~/local_dir -o user=domainUserName,dom=domainName,pass=yourPassword
```

Check the result:

```
$ ls -l ~/local_dir

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 ago 30 08:09 local_dir
```

Note that the problem is the local_dir owner and group (root). Your user and group needed to be there, right? Let's fix it:

```
$ sudo umount ~/local_dir
```

And the final solution:

```
$ sudo mount.cifs //your_server/share ~/local_dir -o user=domainUserName,dom=domainName,pass=yourPassword,rw,uid=yourLocalLinuxUser,uid=yourLocalLinuxGroup

$ ls -l ~/local_dir

drwxr-xr-x 2 localUser localGrp 0 ago 30 08:09 local_dir
```

Test with:

```
$ touch ~/local_dir/testFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your fstab with `sudo nano /etc/fstab`:

```
//IP_address/share /mnt/Share cifs credentials=/home/MyUser/.credentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,uid=1000 0 0
```

To create the credentials `nano /home/MyUser/.credentials`:

```
username=MyUser
password=MyPassword
```

And change the permissions so only you can read that file:

```
sudo chmod 600 /home/MyUser.credentials
```

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently